# python regex filter out exact string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that filters out matches if they contain "plex" in them.

- plex-release -> should not match
- my-release -> should match
- potato -> should match

Been playing with pythex and came up with this one that works partially:

```
(?![plex])(\w+)[-_](release|version)$
```

However this also messes with any other values containing the letter "p".
I'm trying to come up with a regex that leaves out matches that **only** contain the string "plex" and in this order, not just any letter from the string.

Comment: `plex in line` not enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using this regex.

```py
^((?!plex).)*$
```

Source : [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/q/406230/7348030)